# How to stub AWSXray.captureHTTPsGlobal using Sinon?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, aws-lambda, sinon, aws-xray

In my nodejs lambda function I use AWSXray to simply capture https calls made by the function.

```
const AWSXRay = require("aws-xray-sdk-core");
AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require("https"));
```

In my unit tests how do I mock this?

I have tried mocking it with sinon by:

```
before(async () =>
  await sandbox.stub(AWSXRay, 'captureHTTPsGlobal').returns({})
);

after(async () => {
  await sandbox.restore();
});
```

Getting error in test as:

```
OperationalError: Failed to get the current sub/segment from the context.
    at Object.contextMissingRuntimeError [as contextMissing]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not with Xray, but the way I was writing the tests.

AWSXray will try to capture all https calls. But this scenario should ideally not arise in tests because in an ideal test suite all http/https calls anyway should be stubbed.

I solved the problem by properly mocking the units where https calls were being made.